# Link Entity Attribute Not Displayed in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-365

i have report for CRM with SSRS Report when im run execute query i get all the data i needed.But when i try display all the attribute in my report all data from link entity is not displaying, but when im check in execute query there is data on that attribute, Do i need to add something to display link entity attribute ? Im showing the attribute with this code in my ssrs

```
=First(Fields!mjt_point_of_terminalefce6bb8_mjt_mid_regular.Value)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `first` will always return the first record in the resultset. Is this what you expect? Does the first record have a value?

Comment: i already found the answer, i need to add alias in my link entity properties.

Comment: You should add this as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already works , its look like i need to add alias to all my link entity